# Trying to create an "AND" php code but keep getting syntax errors?

Tags: php

I have the following PHP code that I'm trying to modify:

```
<?php if (($membership))  { ?>
    <?php theme_template( 'form-review.php' ); ?>
    <?php } ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

into this:

```
<?php if (($membership)) && get_current_user_id() == get_the_author_meta('ID') )  { ?>
    <?php theme_template( 'form-review.php' ); ?>
    <?php } ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I know I can use && or || but both didn't work in this case. Not sure what the next step is since search results don't help with "add php" code.

Comment: Count your `(` parentheses `)`.

Comment: why opening and closing php tag for every line ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you've got too many parenthesis. Try this:

```
<?php if ( $membership && get_current_user_id() == get_the_author_meta('ID') )  { ?>
```

Comment: Awesome! I was unaware how many parentheses I had, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I forget the order that php looks at stuff but I feel better if you put parenthesis around the == part.

```
if ($membership && (get_current_user_id() == get_the_author_meta('ID'))) {
//stuff 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php 
    if ( $membership && get_current_user_id() == get_the_author_meta('ID') )  {
        theme_template( 'form-review.php' );
     }
?>
```